# “we’ve special ordered you a uniform” vs “we’ve specially ordered you a uniform”

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, zero-derivation

In the sentence:

- Luckily, we've special ordered you a uniform.

Is *special* correct, should or it be *specially*?

As written, which part of the sentence is *special* as an adjective related to?

Comment: [answer redacted]

Comment: Some dialects of English use adjectives as adverbs.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Please stop answering questions in comments.

Comment: @WeatherVane That is not what this is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're deriving a verb from a noun. No grammatical changes are needed.

The noun *special order* is per the OED:

> ***special order***  *n.* a directive issued in a particular situation or under
> special circumstances;  (b) an order placed by a customer for an item
> which a shop does not have or keep in stock; (also) an order placed
> for an item which needs to be specially made or customized.
>
> - 2009   M. C. Lamia & M. J. Krieger *White Knight Syndrome* vi. 92
>      He offered to place a special order for her, even though the supplements were in stock, just so he could get her phone number.

When we use a compound noun like this as a verb via zero derivation, we typically hyphenate it in print, but this is not a grammatical change. The OED gives the verb as:

> ***special-order***  *v*. *North American transitive* to place an order for (an item which a shop does not currently have or keep in stock); (also) to place an order for (an item which needs to be specially made or customized); cf. ***special order*** *n*. (b).
>
> - 2014   *Globe & Mail* (Canada) (*Nexis*) 5 Mar. l1  
>    They no longer stock Arabic-Haitian *kibi*, but they can now be special ordered by the dozen, with two days notice.

Comment: So (1') Luckily, we've special-ordered you a uniform.